# Как хранить обьем данных больше 5 mb на стороне клиента?

Tags: веб-программирование, webbrowser, phonegap, jquery-mobile

Сейчас пишу мобильное приложение с использованием PhoneGap и jQuery mobile. Оно получает некий каталог данных с сервера в формате json преобразует его в строки и записывает в localStorage. Пока места хватает.

Но что делать если каталог увеличится и попросту не будет помещаться туда?

Вариант получение данных частями, не рассматриваю так как приложение служит как офлайн справочник. Тоесть 1 раз подключился к сети получил актуальные данные с сервера и пошел использовать их в офлайне.

Comment: Мм, используйте базы данных, например https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage. Я как-то странно представляю, если вы захотите вывести сразу все 5мб текста на экран.

Comment: Вот я дурак. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы сохранение большого объема информации на стороне клиента 
можно использовать  базы данных такие как [Web SQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) или [IndexedDB](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

Для Phonegap существует целое множество плагинов для работы с ними.

Также рекомендую проверить поддерживает ли webview устройств для которых ведется разработка эти БД.